# Electrical isues on j10 nissan qashqai

Tags: electrical, nissan, electronics

I have a problem with my Nissan Qashqai, its a late 2010 so its a facelift model. The lights flicker when I am driving, when im parked, basically all the time, my windows roll down slowly, some electronics have started dying, like my alarm system, and the latest is my rear & side mirror heaters. Any idea why is this happening ? its a 1.5 dci, original battery, and the voltage fluctuates, the flickering gets worse if ac is on, heated seats, or phone charger. I can turn everything off but it still continues to flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much hit the nail on the head with "original battery". A decent battery will last 3-5 years before it starts to fail/cause issues, so first port of call will be to a store to get a new like-for-like battery. Beyond that, your alternator might be failing but you should get a new battery anyway.

Comment: is there anything less expensive i could try first?

Comment: Borrow a decent battery from a friend? Take your battery to a workshop and have them load/soak test it to get a charge/discharge profile? These things will likely cost money though, and batteries aren't that expensive.

Comment: i will definitely try that once i will have the chance. I know a shop that can test batteries for their health

Comment: Perfect. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

Your symptoms sound much more like a problem with the alternator/charging system. If the car is running, the charging system should be taking most of the load even if the battery is no good, and it generally sounds like yours is having trouble keeping up with the normal demands of the vehicle. Definitely get your alternator tested. (I have personally been in a couple of vehicles when the alternator died, and what your car is doing sounds a lot like that. lights get dim, radio fails, basically all electrics start to go out and then the engine stops)

Also note your battery may still be bad, and a bad alternator can wreck a good battery over time. This also means replacing your battery before having the charging system investigated could be a waste of money, so I would hold off on that till everything else is cleared up first.

Comment: do you know how to check the charging system ? do i need to do a mechanic to do that ?

Comment: You can do a basic voltage check to start, with the engine running. If it's not adequate, then you most definitely have a problem. You can get a false negative though where the voltage looks ok, but will drop when the system is under load. So to do a complete test you usually need a special load tester or to go to a mechanic.

Comment: Its fluctuating between 13.9 - 13.2 with some spikes

Comment: That's ballpark but possibly a little low. If that is not a reading with a load tester I would get that done. A place like Autozone may be able to do this for free and mechanic shops may also not charge for just the test.